# Sublime Text: Некорректно работает подстановка кода в CSS по Tab

Tags: sublime-text

Проблема в том, что если я пишу какое значение через дефис и нажимаю на Tab, Sublime подставляет всё, что угодно, но только не ту фразу, которую предлагает сам.

Sublime у меня последней версии на данный момент - 4126.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В SCSS возникают такие моменты. Вставляется то, что выделено зеленым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю Вам легче всего будет снести файл конфигурации и поставить заново. По умолчанию такого поведения нет

Comment: Именно это я и сделал. Снес всё полностью и поставил заново. И всё то же самое.

Comment: Понял Вас, возможно косяки последней версии, имхо. Удачи с поиском

Comment: Я наверное задам глупый вопрос, а emmet у вас установлен? В нём, к примеру, `fz12 + tab` распаковывается в `font-size: 12px;` без пяти дополнительных вариантов.  А `ttu + tab` в `text-transform: uppercase;`. Вы же набираете какие-то чересчур длинные примеры текста.

Comment: действительно странный вопрос, потому что именно emmet и сбоит. а набираю я длинный запрос для того, чтобы дождаться подсказки

Comment: Мне как раз это было не очевидно. Так как по фразе "font-s" в вашем наборе больше похоже, что работает auto_complete самого саблайма. Опять же спрошу глупость, но отключён ли auto_complete? Может он с эмметом конфликтует?

Comment: Отключил auto_complete - просто убирает подсказки и всё, а при нажатии на Tab опять идет "font: s"

Comment: @Quazimorda в SCSS вдруг возникает такое, как бы двойная подсказка (добавил в основной пост)